# Python Regex - detecting and deleting email address from a long string

Tags: python, regex

I have long string containing email addresses. Most of them have duplicates in the form:

```
addresses = 'zzz@zzz.com <zzz@zzz.com>, aaaaa@aaa.co.uk <aaaaa@aaa.co.uk>, bbb@bbb.org <bbb@bbb.org>,'
```

etc

I would like to erase the duplicate inside <>, so the string would be

```
addresses = 'zzz@zzz.com, aaaaa@aaa.co.uk, bbb@bbb.org,'
```

etc

Unfortunately I cannot put together proper Regex in Python 3. Can anybody help me?

Comment: you actually do have <> around doubles ?

Comment: Be interesting to know here you're getting these emails from and if some of them are actually quoted as they might be - eg if you had `addresses = '"zzz@zzz.com" <zzz@zzz.com>, "aaaaa@aaa.co.uk" <aaaaa@aaa.co.uk>, "bbb@bbb.org" <bbb@bbb.org>'` then running `email.utils.getaddresses([addresses])` with a bit of post-processing to only take the 2nd element works nicely...

Comment: Jon Clements - yes, I have there the <> around the double :-)

Comment: There is no real duplication of addresses in your string `addresses`. In fact, according to [RFC 822, paragraph "3.4 Address Specification"](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt), an email address can be put between angular brackets and preceeded by a display name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just search between the `<>`:

```
import re
addresses = 'zzz@zzz.com <zzz@zzz.com>, aaaaa@aaa.co.uk <aaaaa@aaa.co.uk>, bbb@bbb.org <bbb@bbb.org>,'

emails = ', '.join(re.findall("\<(.*?)\>", addresses))
```

Output:

```
'zzz@zzz.com, aaaaa@aaa.co.uk, bbb@bbb.org'
```

To specifically remove the brackets and addresses between them:

```
emails = re.sub("\<.*?\>", '', addresses)
```

Output:

```
 'zzz@zzz.com , aaaaa@aaa.co.uk , bbb@bbb.org ,'
```

It was pointed out to me the escaping `<>` is not a good idea when used in POSIX. Instead, this can be done:

```
new_data = ', '.join(i for i in addresses.split() if "<" not in i and ">" not in i)
```

Comment: He wants to capture the ones not inside the brackets.

Comment: Escaping `<` and `>` is a very bad idea. In POSIX, `\<` and `\>` are word boundaries. Best practice is to only escape what must be escaped.

Comment: @Ajax1234 Thank you, it works perfectly, particularly the re.sub... version, because this one does not touch email addresses which do not have the duplicates Thank you so much :-)